# Using custom kernel in opencv 2DFilter - causing crash ... convolution how?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, convolution

Thought I'd try my hand at a little (auto)correlation/convolution today in openCV and make my own 2D filter kernel.

Following openCV's [2D Filter Tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html) I discovered that making your own kernels for openCV's [Filter2D](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=filter2d#filter2d) *might* not be that hard. However I'm getting unhandled exceptions when I try to use one.

Code with comments relating to the issue here:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    //Loading the source image
    Mat src;
    src = imread( "1.png" );

    //Output image of the same size and the same number of channels as src.
    Mat dst;
    //Mat dst = src.clone();   //didn't help...

    //desired depth of the destination image
    //negative so dst will be the same as src.depth()
    int ddepth = -1;        

    //the convolution kernel, a single-channel floating point matrix:
    Mat kernel = imread( "kernel.png" );
    kernel.convertTo(kernel, CV_32F);     //<<not working
    //normalize(kernel, kernel, 1.0, 0.0, 4, -1, noArray());  //doesn't help

    //cout << kernel.size() << endl;  // ... gives 11, 11

    //however, the example from tutorial that does work:
    //kernel = Mat::ones( 11, 11, CV_32F )/ (float)(11*11);

    //default value (-1,-1) here means that the anchor is at the kernel center.
    Point anchor = Point(-1,-1);

    //value added to the filtered pixels before storing them in dst.
    double delta = 0;

    //alright, let's do this...
    filter2D(src, dst, ddepth , kernel, anchor, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );

    imshow("Source", src);     //<< unhandled exception here
    imshow("Kernel", kernel);
    imshow("Destination", dst);
    waitKey(1000000);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, using the tutorials kernel works fine, but my image will crash the program, I've tried changing the bit-depth, normalizing, checking size and lots of commenting out blocks to see where it fails, but haven't cracked it yet.

The image is, '1.png':

[image: 1.png]

And the kernel I want 'kernel.png':

[image: kernel.png]

I'm trying to see if I can get a hotspot in dst at the point where the eye catchlight is (the kernel I've chosen *is* the catchlight). I know there are other ways to do this, but I'm interested to see how effective convolving the catchlight over itself is. (autocorrelation I think that's called?)

Direct questions:

- why the crash?
- is the crash indicating a fundamental conceptual mistake?
- or (hopefully) is it just some (silly) fault in the code?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion error should be posted which would help someone to answer you other than questioning why is the crash. Anyways, I have posted below the possible errors and solution for convolution filter2D.

Error 1:

**OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.channels() == 1 && func != 0) in cv::countNo
nZero, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\st
at.cpp, line 549**

Solution : Your input Image and the kernel should be grayscales. You can use the flag 0 in imread. (ex. **cv::imread("kernel.png",0)** to read the image as grayscale.) If you want to apply different kernels to different channels, split the image into separate color planes using split() and process them individually.

I don't see anything other than the obove error that may crash. Kernel size should in odd numbers and your kernel image is 11X11 which is fine. If it stills crashes kindly provide more information in order to help you out.

Comment: Quite right! I even wrote 'a single-channel floating point matrix' in my comments... However in my defence the only feedback I got from VS was "Unhandled exception at at 0x00007FF8C6EA8B9C in opencvTEST.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000521B2DED30." No mention of "(src.channels() == 1 && func != 0)" How do you access that?  And furthermore, it was the kernel not the src that needed to be one channel, src being 3 channel worked ...  But of course, thanks for your help, is working now (but not quite as I hoped, but that's another discussion :)