# OpenCV Prewitt from scratch weirdness

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Because this is a project for an image processing class, I have to implement a couple of linear filters from scratch( I'm not supposed to use already implemented features of OpenCV like Sobel, not even the 2D filter function). The code is at the end of the question.

Since images processed with the Sobel operator give similar results with the Prewitt ones, I used as a test a window where I display a Sobel-processed image.
I only got to the point where I applied an operator on the horizontal direction, but I'm already getting weird results. Images speak for themselves:

Original image:
[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQuH3.png)

My result using the Prewitt operator on the horizontal direction:
[My processed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSOtw.jpg)

I get a weird blue-beige pattern instead of a black-and-white horizontal lines. What is happening?

Here is the code:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int, char** argv)
{


    int Hprewitt[3][3] = { { -1, 0, 1 }, { -1, 0, 1 }, { -1, 0, 1 } };
    int Vprewitt[3][3] = { { -1, -1, -1 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 1, 1, 1 } };
    int tempInput[3][3];
    int tempPixel=0;

    Mat src, src_gray;
    Mat grad;
    const char* window_name = "Sobel Edge Detector";
    const char* window_name2 = "Prewitt";
    int scale = 1;
    int delta = 0;
    int ddepth = CV_16S;
    int computedIntensity;
    src = imread(argv[1]);
    if (src.empty())
    {
        return -1;
    }

        namedWindow(window_name2, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        Mat HprewittMat(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
        GaussianBlur(src, src, Size(3, 3), 0, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
        cvtColor(src, src_gray, COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        namedWindow(window_name, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        Scalar intensity = src.at<uchar>(Point(50, 50)); // this is how to access intensity at a certain pixel
        Vec3b scalarTempPixel = src.at<Vec3b>(Point(1, 1));

        cout << "Pixel (50,50) has intensity: " << intensity.val[0] << endl;


        // applying horizontal prewitt operator
        cout << "\n Image has resolution: " << src.cols << "x" << src.rows << "\n";

            for (int i = 2; i < src.cols-1; i++){ // currently going from column 2 to n-2, same for row
                for (int j = 2; j < src.rows-1; j++){
        // storing a temporary 3x3 input matrix centered on the current pixel
                //  cout << "Matrix centered on pixel: [" << i << "," << j << "] \n";
                    for (int k = -1; k < 2; k++){
                        for (int l = -1; l < 2; l++){
                            intensity = src.at<uchar>(Point(i + k, j + l));
                            tempInput[k+1][l+1] = intensity.val[0];
                        //  cout << "[" << intensity.val[0] << "]";
                        }
                //      cout << " \n";
                    }
// convolution of horizontal prewitt kernel with current 3x3 matrix
                    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
                        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++){
                            tempPixel = tempPixel + tempInput[x][y] * Hprewitt[x][y];
                        }
                    }

                    scalarTempPixel[0] = tempPixel;
                    HprewittMat.at<Vec3b>(Point(i, j)) = scalarTempPixel;
                }
            }


        Mat grad_x, grad_y;
        Mat abs_grad_x, abs_grad_y;
        Sobel(src_gray, grad_x, ddepth, 1, 0, 3, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);
        convertScaleAbs(grad_x, abs_grad_x);
        Sobel(src_gray, grad_y, ddepth, 0, 1, 3, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);
        convertScaleAbs(grad_y, abs_grad_y);
        addWeighted(abs_grad_x, 0.5, abs_grad_y, 0.5, 0, grad);
        imshow(window_name, grad);
        imshow(window_name2, HprewittMat);

        waitKey(0);
        return 0;
    }
```

So at this point I'm doing the following:
I'm reading an image in "src", then I create the HprewittMat which I initialize it with the number of rows and cols of the original image, but with black pixels. I then convert the src image to a gray one. Then I iterate through each pixel of the original image, and for each pixel I'm doing a convolution mask with the the surrounding pixels and the horizontal prewitt kernel. Then I store that value in "tempPixel" and put it in the HprewittMat image.
The next step would be to do the same but with the vertical kernel, and then calculate the gradient kernel.

I'm asking this question because I've found similar questions on how to manipulate individual pixels but usually for python or java. This might also be some flaw in the logic I'm using.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33068453/5008845)

Comment: Are you applying Prewitt to the RGB image `src`?

Comment: Miki, that code is so weird! This initialization method especially is... weird: kernel = (Mat1s(3, 3) << -1, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, +1, +2, +1);
@beaker: Haha! Thanks for the heads up, I totally missed that part. I modified a bit of the code and I think it kinda works now. On of the problems was that at the end of the loop I never re-initialized tempPixel to 0 so its value kept growing.
This is the code at the end of the loop now: 
magTempPixel = sqrt(xtempPixel*xtempPixel + ytempPixel *ytempPixel);
HprewittMat.at<Vec3b>(j, i)[0] = magTempPixel;

Should I answer my own question with the solution?

Comment: Sure, if your code is working now, go ahead and answer.