# How to create cvSobel function using opencv

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, edge-detection, sobel

I am studying about `opencv` and I am using `ver 2.4.10` and `VS2010`
And I have used `cvSobel` function.

I want to make that function. Because I will input another element in that function, called isotropic `sobel` operator.

Please help me how to make that `cvSobel` function. I tried to make and find but, I couldn't make and find. Or tell me to apply kernel on image.

```
cvSobel(src,dst,xorder,yorder,int aparture_size=3);
```

What I really want is to apply following matrix

```
{{-1,0,1},{-sqrt(2.0),0,sqrt(2.0)},{-1,0,1}}
```

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33068453/5008845). A better approach is to use SepFilter2D or filter2D as in the answer below. And if you are not required to program in C, don't use C api, they are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create and apply needed filter kernel using [SepFilter2D](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#sepfilter2d) - your kernel is separable, or [filter2D](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html) for common case