# Sobel edge detection Implementation

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, sobel

I am trying to implement sobel edge detection from scratch but my output can't seem to match with OpenCV's sobel function. I performed correlation on the image with the sobel operator in both x and y directions and then computed gradient magnitude as square root of sum of squares of magnitudes in both x & y direction. I believe the problem is how I assign the threshold for edge detection.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <math.h>

using namespace cv; 
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
// Reading image
Mat img = imread("1.jpg");

// Displaying image
//imshow("Original Image",img);
//waitKey(0);

// Converting to grayscale
Mat img_gray,image_blur;
GaussianBlur( img, image_blur, Size(5,5), 3, 3);
cvtColor(image_blur,img_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);


// Displaying grayscale image
//imshow("Original Image",img_gray);
//waitKey(0);


int cols = img_gray.cols;
int rows = img_gray.rows;

// Creating sobel operator in x direction
int sobel_x[3][3] = {-1,0,1,-2,0,2,-1,0,1};
// Creating sobel operator in y direction
int sobel_y[3][3] = {-1,-2,-1,0,0,0,1,2,1};


int radius = 1;

// Handle border issues
Mat _src;
copyMakeBorder(img_gray, _src, radius, radius, radius, radius, BORDER_REFLECT101);

// Create output matrix
Mat gradient_x = img_gray.clone();
Mat gradient_y = img_gray.clone();
Mat gradient_f = img_gray.clone();

int max=0;

// Correlation loop in x direction 

// Iterate on image 
for (int r = radius; r < _src.rows - radius; ++r)
{
    for (int c = radius; c < _src.cols - radius; ++c)
    {
        int s = 0;

        // Iterate on kernel
        for (int i = -radius; i <= radius; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = -radius; j <= radius; ++j)
            {
                s += _src.at<uchar>(r + i, c + j) * sobel_x[i + radius][j + radius];
            }
        }
        gradient_x.at<uchar>(r - radius, c - radius) = s/30;

        /*if(s>200)
            gradient.at<uchar>(r - radius, c - radius) = 255;
        else
            gradient.at<uchar>(r - radius, c - radius) = 0;
        */    
    }
}

Mat absGrad_x;
convertScaleAbs( gradient_x, absGrad_x );

// Conrrelation loop in y direction 

// Iterate on image 
for (int r = radius; r < _src.rows - radius; ++r)
{
    for (int c = radius; c < _src.cols - radius; ++c)
    {
        int s = 0;

        // Iterate on kernel
        for (int i = -radius; i <= radius; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = -radius; j <= radius; ++j)
            {
                s += _src.at<uchar>(r + i, c + j) * sobel_y[i + radius][j + radius];
            }
        }

        gradient_y.at<uchar>(r - radius, c - radius) = s/30;

        /*if(s>200)
            gradient.at<uchar>(r - radius, c - radius) = 255;
        else
            gradient.at<uchar>(r - radius, c - radius) = 0;
        */    
    }
}

Mat absGrad_y;
convertScaleAbs( gradient_y, absGrad_y );

//Mat absGrad;
/*for(int i=0; i<gradient_f.rows; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<gradient_f.cols; j++)
    {
        absGrad.at<uchar>(i,j) = sqrt( pow(absGrad_x.at<uchar>(i,j),2) + pow(absGrad_y.at<uchar>(i,j),2) );  

         if(absGrad.at<uchar>(i,j) >240)
            absGrad.at<uchar>(i,j) = 100;
        else
            absGrad.at<uchar>(i,j) = 0;
    }
}
*/


//Calculating gradient magnitude
for(int i=0; i<gradient_f.rows; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<gradient_f.cols; j++)
    {
        gradient_f.at<uchar>(i,j) = sqrt( pow(gradient_x.at<uchar>(i,j),2) + pow(gradient_y.at<uchar>(i,j),2) );  

         if(gradient_f.at<uchar>(i,j) >240)
            gradient_f.at<uchar>(i,j) = 100;
        else
            gradient_f.at<uchar>(i,j) = 0;
    }
}



/*
imshow("grad x",gradient_x);
waitKey(0);


imshow("grad y",gradient_y);
waitKey(0);
*/

imshow("grad magnitude",gradient_f);
waitKey(0);

//imshow("absolute grad magnitude",absGrad);
//  waitKey(0); 

//Sobel edge detection function from OpenCV
cv::Mat Gx, Gy; int ksize=3;
Mat abs_grad_x, abs_grad_y;
cv::Sobel(img_gray, Gx, CV_8U, 1, 0, ksize);
convertScaleAbs( Gx, abs_grad_x );
cv::Sobel(img_gray, Gy, CV_8U, 0, 1, ksize);
convertScaleAbs( Gy, abs_grad_y );
Mat grad;
addWeighted( abs_grad_x, 0.5, abs_grad_y, 0.5, 0, grad );

imshow("Sobel Image",grad);
waitKey(0);

return 0;

}
```

Images-

1.Original Image-
[image]

2. My implementation of Sobel Edge Detection
   [image]
3. Opencv Sobel edge function output
   [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sobel derivative in OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972513/sobel-derivative-in-opencv)

Comment: Hey Miki, I've used your code for the correlation part to compute magnitude in X & Y direction. But after computing the gradient magnitude and putting threshold, my output image isn't as good as the one produced by the OpenCV function. Do you have any idea why, is it because of the threshold I used?