# Performing Sobel using Lookup Table causes error

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use `cv::LUT()` to apply a sobel kernel to my `Mat`. Ie, I'm trying to do my own sobel for learning purposes.

But when I use `cv::LUT()` I get the error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((lutcn == cn || lutcn == 1) && _lut.total() == 2
>   56 && _lut.isContinuous() && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_8S)) in cv::LUT, fil
>   e C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\convert.c
>   pp, line 5917

Whats going wrong?

```
void sobel(const Mat& src, Mat& horizGradient, Mat& vertGradient)
{
    float kernelX[3][3] = {
        { -1, 0, 1 },
        { -2, 0, 2 },
        { -1, 0, 1 }
    };

    float kernelY[3][3] = {
        { -1, -2, -1 },
        {  0,  0,  0 },
        {  1,  2,  1 }
    };

    Mat kernelXMat(3, 3, CV_32FC1, &kernelX);
    Mat kernelYMat(3, 3, CV_32FC1, &kernelY);

    LUT(src, kernelXMat, horizGradient); // error occurs on this line
    /*LUT(src, kernelYMat, vertGradient);*/
}
```

PS: Whats the most efficient way to build simple kernel's (Guassian, Laplacian, Sobel, Harrise) in OpenCV?

*Maybe I cant use a `cv::LUT()` to perform sobel? And I should just use 2 for loops?*

Comment: You can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33068453/5008845) how to initialize matrices correctly, and how to implement the convolution with 4 (not just 2!) for loops. Also using a LUT doesn't make any sense here.

Answer (score 0):

`cv::LUT` is not used to apply filters. It is for instance used to do **[color mapping](https://www.learnopencv.com/applycolormap-for-pseudocoloring-in-opencv-c-python/)**.

To achieve what you want, you can use the [`cv::filter2D`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga27c049795ce870216ddfb366086b5a04) function.

Here is an example that shows how to apply your filters:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat image = imread("lena.bmp");
    Mat grey;
    cvtColor(image, grey, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    float kernelX[3][3] = {
        { -1, 0, 1 },
        { -2, 0, 2 },
        { -1, 0, 1 }
    };

    float kernelY[3][3] = {
        { -1, -2, -1 },
        { 0,  0,  0 },
        { 1,  2,  1 }
    };

    Mat kernelXMat(3, 3, CV_32FC1, &kernelX);
    Mat kernelYMat(3, 3, CV_32FC1, &kernelY);
    Mat horizGradient, vertGradient, gradient;

    filter2D(grey, horizGradient, -1, kernelXMat, Point(-1, -1));
    filter2D(grey, vertGradient, -1, kernelYMat, Point(-1, -1));

    gradient = max(horizGradient, vertGradient); // combining the two gradients

    imshow("horizGradient", horizGradient);
    imshow("vertGradient", vertGradient);
    imshow("gradient", gradient);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the result:
[image: sobel filter on lena]

Hope it helps!